# GeoCoding using Google GeoCoding API for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, geocoding

How to send a collection of address in an array for a geocoding service using Google Geocoding API, I am successfully getting the response for single entity but what about a collection of an array.

Thank You!!

Comment: Enumrate the array and do the same process that you do for single entity?

Comment: @Bhumit Its crashing when I use the same in array